# Binding a button to multiple boolean values javafx

Tags: java, user-interface, button, javafx

I have 5 textFields and they all have validators that I have created for them. When the field has been validated and is correct, I call a method that sets a group to become visible:

```
public void fadeInLabel(Group groupName){
    groupName.setOpacity(0);
    groupName.setVisible(true);
    FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(300), groupName);
    ft.setInterpolator(Interpolator.EASE_OUT);
    ft.setFromValue(0);
    ft.setToValue(1);
    ft.play();
}
```

I would like to make a button enabled when all of the groups associated with the validators of these text fields are visible.

I have tried using a BooleanBinding but it does not allow me to bind a boolean value - I have to bind a boolean property.

EDIT: 
Following is the code that i attempted but came back with an error 'boolean can not be dereferenced'

```
BooleanBinding accountBind = completeLabel0.isVisible().or(completeLabel1.isVisible());
createButton.disableProperty().bind(accountBind);
```

Comment: *"I have tried using a BooleanBinding but it does not allow me to bind a boolean value - I have to bind a boolean property."* This is not true. The [`bind`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/Property.html#bind-javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue-) method accepts any `ObservableValue<Boolean>`. Post the relevant code (i.e. where you have attempted to bind the button's `disableProperty()`.)

Comment: Not entirely sure what your code looks like, but a a boolean property can happen standalone, and can trigger any code by change listener.

Comment: @James_D i have edited the post, code is above^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BooleanBinding accountBind = completeLabel0.isVisible().or(completeLabel1.isVisible());
createButton.disableProperty().bind(accountBind);
```

should be

```
BooleanBinding accountBind = completeLabel0.visibleProperty().or(completeLabel1.visibleProperty());
createButton.disableProperty().bind(accountBind);
```

assuming `completeLabel0` and `completeLabel1` are some kind of node.